# Changing Screenshot format from PNG to JPEG?

Tags: screenshots

I want to change the screenshot function to take screenshots using JPEG rather than PNG. The JPEG should also have time & date info. Are there any apps/magisk modules that do this?

Root methods prefered so as to still have the system screenshot functions

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about Magisk module that can do this but here is an app alternative

[Touchshot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jbs.util.takescreen) is an app I use

- Hover button (overlay)
- `JPEG / PNG` - JPEG quality 80 /90 /100 and resolution can be varied from 640 x 360 , 1280 x 720, 1920 x 1080
- Date and time stamped screenshots for instance `20171229_140953.jpg` for a screenshot just captured

Comment: It's good but it's a bit bloated. Problem is that it doesn't do the system screenshot stuff (scroll capture, take screenshots on snapchat since it probably uses a different api) and would be nice if it had a button mapper shortcut.